# .net core asp.net web api action returning unexpected status code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core

I have set up this action:

```
[HttpPost]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Category), StatusCodes.Status201Created)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAsync(CategoryViewModel category)
{
    if (category == null) return BadRequest();
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
    if (!category.Fields.Any()) return BadRequest();

    var request = Factory.Create(category);

    _categoryService.Save(request);
    await _categoryService.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Ok(category);
}
```

The response type should be **Category** with a status code of 201, but when I run my tests I get a status code of 200.
This is my test:

```
    [Test]
    public async Task CreateCategory()
    {
        // Assemble
        const string categoryId = "cameras";
        var services = ControllerContext.GivenServices();
        var controller = services.WhenCreateController();
        var field = new Field { CategoryId = categoryId, Name = "Title" };
        var category = new CategoryViewModel { Id = categoryId, Name = "Cameras", Fields = new List<Field>{ field } };

        // Act
        var result = await controller.CreateAsync(category);
        var okObjectResult = result as OkObjectResult;

        // Assert
        okObjectResult.Should().NotBeNull();
        Assert.AreEqual(StatusCodes.Status201Created, okObjectResult?.StatusCode);

        services.MockCategoryService.Verify(m => m.Save(It.IsAny<Category>()), Times.Once);
        services.MockCategoryService.Verify(m => m.SaveChangesAsync(), Times.Once);
    }
```

This test fails on this line: `Assert.AreEqual(StatusCodes.Status201Created, okObjectResult?.StatusCode);` because it is returning 200 instead.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Why do you think it should be `201`? You're calling the `Ok()` method (as in `OK 200`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ProducesResponseType-Attribute is not what determines what your Action returns, [it is used for things like swagger/OpenAPI to create documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#iactionresult-type).

You need to change the return value of your Action to `return Created(UriOfTheCreatedResource, category)` instead of `return Ok(category)`.

[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.created?view=aspnetcore-2.2)